# How can I redirect all unknown URLs in lift framework?

Tags: scala, redirect, lift

I'm not very familiar with lift framework and wanted to know if the following use case is possible using lift framework.

On server1, Lift is serving REST webservice at following url "/contact/"

However, if the client sends request to the following URL https://server1/contact/meet/" then it is not implemented on this specific server but "might" be implemented by another server. Can Lift redirect any such unsupported URLs to some specific server? Eg, in 302 response, can Location be specified by Lift to https://server2/contact/meet/ ?

Please note that these are unknown URLs and can't be configured statically.

Comment: So first you don't want server1 to return 404 when certain url are not served but redirect to 
server2? second if the urls are unknown so do you know the urls or url pattern 
that can be served by server1?

Comment: Yes. I don't want 404 to be sent but instead redirect any such URL to server 2. All the URLs will begin with the same path eg, /contact/. However, /contact/join will be implemented on server1 and /contact/meet will be implemented on server2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I get it. Maybe you need **`LiftRules.dispatch`** and **`net.liftweb.http.DoRedirectResponse`**. Following is the code I try to solve your trouble.

```
// The code should in the server1; JsonDSL will be used by JsonResponse
class Boot extends Bootable with JsonDSL {
   def boot {
       initDispatch
   }


   def initDispatch {
      LiftRules.dispatch.append { 

        case Req("contact" :: url :: Nil, _, GetRequest) => {
            () => Full(
                if (url == "join") {
                    // or other url that match what will be implemented in server1

                    // your implementation, say JsonResponse
                    JsonResponse("server1" -> true)
                } else {
                    // if the url part does not match simply redirect to server2, 
                   // then you have to deal with how to process the url in server2

                    DoRedirectResponse("https://server2/contact/meet/")
                }
            )
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Anyway, hope it helps.