# Scala/Lift- How do I do a page redirect with params?

Tags: scala, lift

I need to redirect all the requests for 'toolsearch' page to 'search' page with all the parameters

so `localhost:8080/toolsearch#?q=20` needs to be redirected to `localhost:8080/search#?q=20`

I am trying to use Boot to add liftrules for the redirect

```
    LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend {
      case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("toolsearch" :: Nil, "", x, y), z, s) => {        
        RewriteResponse("search" :: "index" :: Nil, Map("page" -> "search")) //Works but the browser address bar says 'toolsearch' not 'search
//        S.redirectTo("/search") //throws net.liftweb.http.ResponseShortcutException: Shortcut
//        JsCmds.RedirectTo("/search") //doesnt compile
      }
    }
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time trying different things this is the solution that I found that works:

```
LiftRules.dispatch.prepend {
  case Req("toolsearch" :: Nil, _, _) =>{
    () => Full(RedirectResponse("/search"))
  }
}
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747110/how-can-i-redirect-all-unknown-urls-in-lift-framework)

Please let me know if you have a better solution.